# Comparing two text columns and flag it with true or false with new column

Tags: r

I am new to programming and my question is to match or compare two character columns and flag if matches as True or False.

I have dataframe with two character columns as below

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("1-C2", "2-C1", "2-C2", "1-C1"), 
                 v2 = c("1-C2", "2-C2", "2-C2", "1-C1"))
```

now I need to match columns each row and flag it true if it matches or else false.

Comment: Have you come across the `==` function?

Answer (score 5):

One in a gazillion ways to do it:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("1-C2", "2-C1", "2-C2", "1-C1"), 
                 v2 = c("1-C2", "2-C2", "2-C2", "1-C1"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df$Match <- df$v1 == df$v2
```

or

```
df$Match <- as.character(df$v1) == as.character(df$v2)
```

when you want to keep the factors in the data.frame.

Comment: Hello Martin, Thanks for the reply. But, I have more than 100 rows to match.

Comment: And that leads to what problem?

Comment: HI Martin, In case if I need to truncate the C1 or last text part and update in new column.

Comment: @VivekanandanRamalingam that sounds like a new question. Seems like your question has been answered - I'd recommend accepting this answer and opening a new question if you have outstanding problems. We don't like to move the goalposts here.

Answer (score -1):

I am unclear whether *"and flag if matches"* refers to equality matching (which is what most answers have assumed), or whether you are interested in partial-matching entries from columns `v1` and `v2`. For example, do you consider entries `v1="1-C2"` and `v2="1-C2_something_else"` a match?

**If it is partial matching you are after**, you can use `grepl` to flag partial matches of `v1` in `v2`.

For example, using base R's `mapply` and `grepl`:

```
mapply(grepl, df$v1, df$v2)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or the same using `purrr::map2_lgl`:

```
purrr::map2_lgl(df$v1, df$v2, grepl)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Note: As @Gregor pointed out, **if you are after equality matching, my approach will give wrong results**, as entries `v1="1-C2"` and `v2="21-C2"` will be successfully partially matched (as `1-C2` is contained within `21-C2`).

Comment: This isn't comparing equality, it's comparing whether `v2` contains `v1` as a substring.

Comment: @Gregor True and still works here conditional on OPs sample data `df$v1`, `df$v2`; also seems to be consistent with OPs statement *"and flag it true if it matches or else false"*.

Comment: A good answer should generalize when possible and draw attention to simple cases where it doesn't. If OP's numbers go into double digits - if among their hundreds of rows they have something like `"12-C11"` in addition to `"2-C1"` this will silently produce incorrect results.

Comment: @Gregor IMO down-vote is a bit harsh, seeing that this does in fact reproduce OPs  expected output; my only intent was to offer a different solution. Also as I pointed out, OPs problem statement is somewhat ambiguous. But fair enough.

Comment: I disagree - both for OP and for future users. This happens to work on OP's specific reproducible example, but doesn't work on simple extensions. If someone asked for help adding numbers with the examples 1+2  and 5+4, a solution that only works for single digit numbers is not a good answer, *especially* if it makes no note of its weakness. I'd remove my downvote if you explain the difference between this and equality checking with an example.

Comment: @Gregor I edited my post to clarify on the points you raised.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
> library(magrittr)
> library(dplyr)
> apply(df,2,function(x) str_sub(x,length(x)-3, 1)) %>% 
    data.frame() %>% mutate(same=(ifelse(v1==v2,TRUE,FALSE)))
  v1 v2 same
1  1  1 TRUE
2  2  2 TRUE
3  2  2 TRUE
4  1  1 TRUE
```